# Можно ли декомпилировать MS SQL Package?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

Можно ли декомпилировать MS SQL Package  и получить исходный проект, который можно открыть в Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Они не компилируются. Формат пактов(dtsx) основан на XML. Т.е. это просто текстовый файл со специальной разметкой.

Создайте в *Business Intelligence Development Studio*, либо в *Visual Studio* установленным *SSDT-BI* новый проект *Integration Services*. Потом в дереве проекта нажмите правой кнопкой на "SSIS Packages", и выберите "Add Existing Package" - вам будет предложено добавить пакет из файла либо с сервера.